# Initialize empty array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization

I've just tried:

```
class Test
{

public:
        int iArray[][];

}
```

...is this not possible? Do I have to set a constant value?

like:

```
class Test
{
public:
       const int iArray[5][4];
}
```

I want to define [x][y] later, just have the placements there. Else it wouldn't be "dynamic" and I don't want to use a vector because I want to be able to access the values by "X" and "Y".

Comment: Did you try it? I did, and I got `error: declaration of iArray as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first` - I think that explains it as well as I can.

Comment: std::vector has a `[]` operator.

Comment: Please show us a scenario of how you want to use this class. What is X and Y?

Comment: Test.iArray[x][y]. If I before runtime want to define a grid of somekind I don't want it to be set by a #define value or a CONST value, it should be define at runtime according to user preference.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason you shouldn't be using a vector here.  For novice C++ programmers, except for instructional purposes, or when you know the exact container size, there's absolutely no reason to be using 'naked' arrays over vectors (which are essentially array structures where all the memory management is handled for you).

Comment: @Slims Novice or not, the most frequent reason for using C style arrays is when they are initialized, and you want the compiler to count the initializers to determine the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
tempalte <int N1, int N2> class Test
{
public:
  int iArray[N1][N2];
};
```

?

Comment: Yes, this would work. I really don't want to use a vector for it. Thanks.

Comment: But please note the difference, many classes (instances of this template) will be created at **compile time**.

Comment: Whats the difference for performance? I'm creating a game and want it to be customizable, therefor nothing "static" and definitive.

Comment: I would suggest that you first check that this allows the required level of flexibility. Then you should see if there is a performance loss. But I don't think it will run slower than the solution with vectors. It could increase the amount of stack space used if you have many local variables of type `Test`.

Answer (score 4):

I think better way to achieve this is to use pointers. You can do like this.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PointerTest {

    private:
        int** array;
        int x, y;
    public :
        void setValue(int row, int col,int value);
        int getValue(int row, int col);
        PointerTest(int row, int col);
       ~PointerTest() {
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
        delete array[y];
    }
        }


};
PointerTest::PointerTest(int row, int col) {
    x=row, y=col;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
        *array=new int[col];
    }
}


void PointerTest::setValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    *(array[row])=value;
}

int PointerTest::getValue(int row, int col) {
    return *(array[row]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PointerTest* t=new PointerTest(4,5);
    t->setValue(0,0,464);
    cout<<"The value in array: "<<t->getValue(0,0)<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about putting a std::vector in a vector?

```
std::vector< std::vector< const int > > iArray;
```

There aren't many reason to use "plain" arrays in C++.

Comment: That's not quite the same thing: it allows raggedness (which `int[][]` doesn't), and it has a separate allocation per line (which can also affect locality).  Writing a simple matrix class based on `std::vector<int>` is not rocket science, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decide `int iArray[][];` size later then you can use `vector< vector<int> > iArray;`.

The other way is to use nested `new[]`, which would be little complex.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. But you can have a pointer in your class like

```
int **ptr;
```

and then in the constructor or where ever allocate the memory for your array with

```
ptr = (int **)malloc( the size you want );
```

or with the "new[]"-operator in C++.

but if you are using C++ .. the best way is to use:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int >> array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test()
  {
    iArray = new int*[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      iArray[i] = new int[4];
  }
  ~Test()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      delete[] iArray[i];
    delete[] iArray;
  }
  int** iArray;
};
```

Will allow you to allocate a 2d int array at runtime (in this example it is a 5x4), but in all honestly I would use vectors as pointed out by some other posters, you don't need to worry about freeing the memory afterwards like you do with the use of new.